# Multiple python lists to json file

Tags: python, json

I am having 6 python lists as follows:

```
dows=['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri']
dates=['10-4', '10-5', '10-6', '10-7', '10-8']
maxs=['24', '23', '17', '16', '18']
mins=['13', '13', '11', '10', '7']
precipitation_probabilities=['0', '0', '76', '70', '21']
wind_speeds=['13', '21', '16', '8', '11']
```

and like to convert them to json, which I want eventually save to a drive as a file (on rasppberry pi) in format as follows:

```
{
    "dows":['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
    "dates":['10-4', '10-5', '10-6', '10-7', '10-8'],
    "maxs":['24', '23', '17', '16', '18'],
    "mins":['13', '13', '11', '10', '7'],
    "precipitation_probabilities":['0', '0', '76', '70', '21'],
    "wind_speeds":['13', '21', '16', '8', '11']
}
```

I've tried everything without luck.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you just want the following python `dict`:

```
my_dict = {"dows": dows, 
           "dates": dates, 
           "maxs": maxs, 
           "mins": mins, 
           "precipitation_probabilities": precipitation_probabilities,
           "wind_speeds": wind_speeds}
```

To get the json string representation of the above dictionary:

```
import json
my_json = json.dumps(my_dict)
```

To write the dictionary to a json file:

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(my_dict, outfile)
```

Comment: OMG! This easy? No way. I've spent like hours of googling and trying. Thank you!